# Getting incorrect values in JuMP

Tags: julia, getvalue, julia-jump

The following code is running correctly. However, when I call for the results one of the variables (utilizado) is returning incorrect values, only zeros. I know there is something I am making incorrectly but I don't know where.

```
using JuMP, Clp
m = Model(solver = ClpSolver())
@variable(m, utilizado[i=1:3] >= 0)
@variable(m, resultado[j=1:2] >= 0)
custo = [90, 120]
disponivel = [8, 6, 5]
matriz= [0.20 0.30;
     0.20 0.25;
     0.15 0.10]
@objective(m, Min, dot(custo, resultado))
@constraint(m,  [i=1:3], sum(matriz[i,j] * resultado[j] for j=1:2) >= 
disponivel[i])
print(m)

status = solve(m)
println("Objective value: ", getobjectivevalue(m))
println("Resultado: ", getvalue(resultado))
println("Resultado: ", getvalue(utilizado))
```

Comment: `utilizado` appears neither in objective nor in constraints. Is this correct?

Comment: @matb You were correctly. I haven't assign `utilizado` to constraints, I assign it and add a disponivel as a lower bound in variables and it works. The final constraing was: `@constraint(m,  [i=1:3], sum(matriz[i,j] * resultado[j] for j=1:2) == utilizado[i])` and the variable:  `@variable(m, utilizado[i=1:3] >= disponivel[i])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code was:

```
using JuMP, Clp
m = Model(solver = ClpSolver())

custo = [90, 120]
disponivel = [8, 6, 5]
matriz= [0.20 0.30;
     0.20 0.25;
     0.15 0.10]

@variable(m, utilizado[i=1:3] >= disponivel[i])
@variable(m, resultado[j=1:2] >= 0)

@objective(m, Min, dot(custo, resultado))
@constraint(m,  [i=1:3], sum(matriz[i,j] * resultado[j] for j=1:2) == utilizado[i])
print(m)
status = solve(m)
println("Objective value: ", getobjectivevalue(m))
println("Resultado: ", getvalue(resultado))
println("Utilizado: ", getvalue(utilizado))
```